# How do you select from mysql where last character in a string = x?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to select rows from the database where the last character in the mov_id column equals to 1 and 2.

How would the query look like?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `mov_id` LIKE '%1' OR `mov_id` LIKE '%2'
```

the `%` character is a wildcard which matches anything (like `*` in many other places)

Comment: Depending on your database and version, this might go through each row of the DB twice due to the 'OR' clause. I would make sure this is well indexed and carefully check out the explain plan.

Comment: Indexes are useless if matched againt LIKE's starting %. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html "... do not use indexes ... the LIKE value begins with a wildcard character."

Comment: @Jacob: have you ever encountered this in a production-grade database?  Any non-broken query planner would scan myTable once and apply this where clause to each record.

Answer (score 9):

If `mov_id` is a numeric value (TINYINT, INT, etc...) then you should use a numeric operator. For instance, use the modulo operator to keep the last digit

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (mov_id MOD 10) IN (1, 2)
```

If `mov_id` is a string, you can use LIKE or [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring). SUBSTRING() will be slightly faster.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTRING(mov_id, -1) IN ('1', '2')
```

If your table is big or that query is frequently run, you should definitely consider adding a column to your table, in which you would store `mov_id`'s last digit/character, and index that column.

Comment: What Josh said - sometimes you have to denormalise and add a column to dramatically improve performance. There is a REVERSE function you can use on text fields (for instance if you want to store email addresses but search on the domain eg .com .org etc), but I don't think it would help in terms of performance in the original setup here.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way too:

```
SELECT field1
FROM table
WHERE RIGHT(field1, 1) = 'x'
```

it displays the fields that has last a value of x.

Comment: this was perfect thanks. must faster than using `%` I suspect as well.

Comment: welcome @anon58192932, we had a lot of difference scenario according to our needs but if this helped your then thanks for the appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE RIGHT(Column_name, 1) IN ('x')
```

if you want to match two character just replace 1 by 2.
In general:

`RIGHT(COLUMN_NAME, NO_OF_CHARACTER_YOU WANT_TO_MATCH_FROM_LAST)`

And if you want to match the starting char just use `LEFT` instead of `RIGHT`

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something like:

```
select
     your, fields, go, here
from table
where
     substring(mov_id, (char_length(move_id) - 1)) = x
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE `mov_id` REGEXP '1$' OR `mov_id` REGEXP '2$'