# Selecting all values that end with certain chars

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a all the cars that end with `a, c, d or f`
I can get a list of cars ending with a doing this:

```
select model 
from cars 
where model like "a%";
```

But I want a list of the models ending not only with a, but also with the other chars above:

I have tried doing this (which doesn't return correct list):

```
select model 
from cars 
where model like "%a"
or model like "%c"
or model like "%d"
or model like "%f";
```

This is also a very ugly attempt/solution. Imagine if I needed more models.

I am using mysql

Thanks for any help

Comment: `Right(model,1) in ('a','c','d','f')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you select from mysql where last character in a string = x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270055/how-do-you-select-from-mysql-where-last-character-in-a-string-x)

Comment: Maybe I am just tired; but what is wrong with the second query?

Comment: @Uueerdo `%` is on the wrong side it seems

Comment: @AaronDietz not if they want it to "end with" those characters.

Comment: @Uueerdo Right, whoops.  I was looking at the first query, didn't realize they were different.

Comment: Second query seems to be correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp`:

```
where model regexp '[acdf]$'
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Would this also work in standard sql, or is it only for mysql. Would I be able to use regexp or substring in sql?

Comment: Many but not all databases support regular expressions, but the syntax tends to vary among them.

Answer (score 1):

```
select model 
from cars
where substring(model, -1) IN ('a','c','d','f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to query
$ means the end of String and ^ means the beginning

```
select model 
from cars 
where model REGEXP "(a|c|d|f)$";
```

If you wanted those characters in the beginning then you could have written:

```
select model 
from cars 
where model REGEXP "^(a|c|d|f)";
```